# Calloc cannot access from a different .c file-

Tags: c, dynamic-allocation, calloc

I am new at c & I met a new issue..

file1.c-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int sec();
char *ptr=NULL;

int main(){
char *ptr=NULL;

ptr=(char*)calloc(sizeof(char),8);/*8 chars.*/
*(ptr+0)='0'; /*first char set to 0.*/

printf("%c\n",*ptr);

*(ptr+0)='r';
*(ptr+1)='o';
*(ptr+2)='i';
*(ptr+3)='L';

printf("%c %c %c %c \n",*(ptr+0),*(ptr+1),*(ptr+2),*(ptr+3));

sec();

return 0;}
```

And file2.c-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char *ptr;

void sec(void){

puts("before.");

*(ptr+0)='L';/*CARSH HERE.*/
*(ptr+1)='i';
*(ptr+2)='o';
*(ptr+3)='r';

puts("after.");

printf("%c %c %c %c ",*(ptr+0),*(ptr+1),*(ptr+2),*(ptr+3));

free(ptr);}
```

I done something like this before(with one difference),but now it crashes.
What is the reason ?.
If I will build a function in the source file, where the memory been allocated it will be solved ?.

Comment: See [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two variables named `ptr`.  One is the global variable, and one is local to `main`.  `main` allocates only the local `ptr`, but then `sec` tries to use the global variable which is still null.

Try removing the `char* ptr=NULL;` declaration from `main` so that both functions use your global variable.

Answer (score 0):

*ptr is declared both globally and locally

local variable has the higher priority hence the memory is allocated to the local *ptr

remove the decleration inside main
it'll Work Fine